# SQL Query to retrieve items based on start time but include the current one

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, postgresql-performance

I'm currently working on a performance issue in a spring boot microservice. We are trying to reduce the amount of queries sent to our PostgreSQL DB in order to improve execution speed of HTTP requests. JPA and Hibernate is in use.

We want to get to get `x` items from the DB which should be ordered by a datetime field `start_time`. The first item should be the "current one", which is defined as the closest `start_time` in the past.

Currently I'm using two separate queries, one to retrieve the "current one", another one to get the next `x - 1` entries.

Here are the queries:

```
fun findTopByStartTimeLessThanEqualOrderByStartTimeDesc(
    instant: Instant
): EventEntity?
```

```
fun findByStartTimeGreaterThanOrderByStartTimedAsc(
    instant: Instant,
    pageable: Pageable
): List<EventEntity>
```

They translate roughly to something like this (`x = 1000`):

```
select * from event where start_time <= now() order by start_time desc limit 1;
```

```
select * from event where start_time > now() order by start_time limit 999;
```

Is there a way to combine those two queries into a single query which has a better performance?

Comment: Maybe a native `union` query of the above two? This will save you a roundtrip to the database and let the optimizer do the rest. And btw `start_time >= now()` in the second one.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm might be worth a try

Comment: you can add index on `start_time` field and also pagination would be nice (if it's applicable)

Comment: @muhammedozbilici some other performance aspects are already considered but I'm still trying to solve this problem here